# GNU Make: startup a Docker Container, make it execute commands, exit container, execute a script

Tags: docker, makefile

I am creating a virtual machine (VM) for an embedded device that runs both C and Java code by compiling both to bytecode.
Now I am trying to automate compiling and flashing C applications (Java already works).

A big manual part is taking a .c file and getting it to a format the VM understands.
Currently, it works as follows:

1. Boot up a Docker Container while pointing it towards where the .c file is and giving myself bash

   ~$ docker run -i -v /home/git/bytecode_manipulation:/c_files -t lljvm_work /bin/bash
2. Use the configured lljvm-cc tool of the container to convert the .c file while producing a jasmin file (an intermediate for converting to bytecode)

   docker_container$ lljvm-cc test_c_srv.c -o test_c_srv -g3
3. Exit the docker container and run a python script which converts the .j jasmin file to a .uj jasmin file, converts the .uj file to a .class file and puts it in a good folder

   ~$ ./script_j_to_uj.py test_c_srv.j test_srv.uj

I'd like to automate this in a Makefile.
Currently, I have a recipe in my makefile that generates .class files for the Java apps, then scoops up all .class files (from either C or Java apps). processes them somewhat further into .raw_ujc files and generates a list of then. Ideally, this would now also generate .class files for the C apps.
The recipe:

```
jre_filelist:
    CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/default_runtime/real:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake/uj \
        javac $(SELF)/default_runtime/real/java/lang/*.java  $(SELF)/default_runtime/UJSrv.java 
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "Exception.class" -type f > $(SELF)/files #First call is overwriting
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "Runnable.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "String.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "StringBuilder.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "Thread.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "Throwable.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "UJSrv.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    $(info findstring C in $(LANG) is $(findstring C, $(LANG)))
ifeq ($(findstring C, $(LANG)),C) # include C runtime
    CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/default_runtime/real:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake/uj:$(SELF)/lljvm \
        javac $(SELF)/lljvm/runtime/*.java
    CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/default_runtime/real:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake/uj:$(SELF)/lljvm \
        javac $(SELF)/lljvm/lib/*.java
    find $(SELF)/lljvm/runtime -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/lljvm/lib -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files    
    $(foreach SRV, $(SRVS_C), \
        find  $(UJ_DIR)/services/c/ -iname "$(SRV).class" -type f | xargs realpath >> $(SELF)/files && \
    ) true  
endif
    $(foreach SRV, $(SRVS_JAVA), \
        CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/default_runtime javac $(UJ_DIR)/services/java/$(SRV).java && \
        find $(UJ_DIR)/services/java/ -iname "$(SRV).class" -type f | xargs realpath >> $(SELF)/files && \
    ) true
    @while read -r file; do \
        $(CMD) "$$file" >/dev/null; \
    done < $(SELF)/files;
    rm -f $(SELF)/files && rm -f ../filelist.txt
    find $(SELF)/default_runtime/ -iname "*.raw_ujc" -type f > ../filelist.txt
ifeq ($(findstring C, $(LANG)),C) # include C runtime
    find $(SELF)/lljvm/ -iname "*.raw_ujc" -type f >> ../filelist.txt
endif   
    $(foreach SRV, $(SRVS_C), \
        find  $(UJ_DIR)/services/c/ -iname "$(SRV).raw_ujc" -type f | xargs realpath >> ../filelist.txt && \
    ) true
    $(foreach SRV, $(SRVS_JAVA), \
        find  $(UJ_DIR)/services/java/ -iname "$(SRV).raw_ujc" -type f | xargs realpath >> ../filelist.txt && \
    ) true
```

So doing these steps is a bit difficult and I was hoping for advice. Main thing is either booting a container or pre-starting a container and feeding it commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering around, I've this does what I want:

```
compile_c:
    docker run -v $(UJ_DIR)/services/c/:/c_files -w /c_files -it lljvm_work \
            /bin/bash -c '../usr/local/lib/lljvm/lljvm-cc $(SRV).c -l_c_support -o $(SRV) -g3'
    sudo python   script_j_to_uj.py $(UJ_DIR)/services/c/$(SRV).j $(UJ_DIR)/services/c/$(SRV).uj
    rm -f $(UJ_DIR)/services/c/$(SRV)
```

In the recipe, it is used as follows:

```
jre_filelist:
    CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/default_runtime/real:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake/uj \
        javac $(SELF)/default_runtime/real/java/lang/*.java  $(SELF)/default_runtime/UJSrv.java 
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "Exception.class" -type f > $(SELF)/files #First call is overwriting
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "Runnable.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "String.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "StringBuilder.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "Thread.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "Throwable.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/ -iname "UJSrv.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    $(info findstring C in $(LANG) is $(findstring C, $(LANG)))
ifeq ($(findstring C, $(LANG)),C) # include C runtime
    CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/default_runtime/real:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake/uj:$(SELF)/lljvm \
        javac $(SELF)/lljvm/runtime/*.java
    CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/default_runtime/real:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake:$(SELF)/default_runtime/fake/uj:$(SELF)/lljvm \
        javac $(SELF)/lljvm/lib/*.java
#   find $(SELF)/default_runtime/real/java/lang/lljvm/util -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
#   find $(SELF)/default_runtime/real//java/lang/lljvm/tools -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
#   find $(SELF)/default_runtime/real//java/lang/lljvm/tools/info -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
#   find $(SELF)/default_runtime/real//java/lang/lljvm/tools/ld -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/lljvm/runtime -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
#   find $(SELF)/default_runtime/real//java/lang/lljvm/io -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(SELF)/lljvm/lib -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files    
    $(foreach SRV, $(SRVS_C), \
        make compile_c SRV=$(SRV) && \
        find  $(UJ_DIR)/services/c/ -iname "$(SRV).class" -type f | xargs realpath >> $(SELF)/files && \
    ) true  
endif
    $(foreach SRV, $(SRVS_JAVA), \
        CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/default_runtime javac $(UJ_DIR)/services/java/$(SRV).java && \
        find $(UJ_DIR)/services/java/ -iname "$(SRV).class" -type f | xargs realpath >> $(SELF)/files && \
    ) true
    @while read -r file; do \
        $(CMD) "$$file" >/dev/null; \
    done < $(SELF)/files;
    rm -f $(SELF)/files && rm -f ../filelist.txt
    find $(SELF)/default_runtime/ -iname "*.raw_ujc" -type f > ../filelist.txt
ifeq ($(findstring C, $(LANG)),C) # include C runtime
    find $(SELF)/lljvm/ -iname "*.raw_ujc" -type f >> ../filelist.txt
endif   
    $(foreach SRV, $(SRVS_C), \
        find  $(UJ_DIR)/services/c/ -iname "$(SRV).raw_ujc" -type f | xargs realpath >> ../filelist.txt && \
    ) true
    $(foreach SRV, $(SRVS_JAVA), \
        find  $(UJ_DIR)/services/java/ -iname "$(SRV).raw_ujc" -type f | xargs realpath >> ../filelist.txt && \
    ) true
```